# Android multi-line textview - character count of a particular line?

Tags: android, count, textview, multiline

I'm trying to get the character count of a particular line of a multi-line textview.  Based on other posts, I've gotten the Layout of the textview in question.  I see several methods that pass in an (int line), but none that return a character count of a particular line?  Am I just missing it?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will split the text in the textview by lines.

```
String text;
String[] lines = text.split("\\r?\\n");
int characterCount = lines[0].length();
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I am assuming that `String text = textView.getText().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

if your just trying to get the count of a string, have you tried String.length(myString) to return a count of how many characters are in the string?